# Find all rows where the nonmissing column values aren't the same

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
1 1 - - 2
1 - 1 - -
- - - 2 2
1 2 - - -
```

The dashes are missing values.

What I want to do is highlight all rows where the nonmissing values are different. In the above fake table, rows 1 & 4 would be highlighted because they have 1s and 2s both. In contrast, row 2 only has 1s and row 3 only has 2s so it wouldn't be highlighted.

I figure I'm supposed to use a custom formula for conditional formatting, but I can't figure out the exact query. Can anyone help me out there?

Comment: Will the rows always have numeric values only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=count(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(filter(A1:E1,A1:E1<>""))))=1
```

[image]

Comment: This was perfect, thanks! I actually ended up using =COUNTIF(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(filter(I2:N2,I2:N2<>""))), "*")=1 as I converted the 1s and 2s to True/False for the sake of clarity. But the core of it is the same.

Comment: countifs seems a little overkill, you can use COUNTA instead: `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(filter(A1:E1,A1:E1<>""))))=1` which will count non numbers also.

Answer (score 1):

custom formula for conditional formating:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR($A1:$E1*1))=2)
```

[image: 0]